# IIS handling url requests for multiple applications within same webstie

Tags: iis

This is definitely out of my area of expertise so I hope I explain this well.  We have a website and within that website we have 2 different applications with 2 different login pages.  What would I have to do so that for example requests for app1.website.com and app2.website.com get's routed to the correct apps login page?

[WebServer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeEgj.png)

Comment: What kind of applications are they? What are the desired URLs you want for the login pages? Have you tried IIS URL Rewrite module already?

Comment: Lexi Li So if you look at the website screenshot I posted I want people to be directed to app 1 when they type in app1.defualtwebsite.com and the same for app2 if that makes sense?  I am not familiar with IIS URL Rewrite module so I will look that up.  Thank you for the response.

Comment: you could try this rule: `<rule name="app1 redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="app1.website.com" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://website.com/react1/app1/" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>` the [site structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCXW2.png) ,[site binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVFoj.png)

Comment: @DisplayName is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes, thank you. @JalpaPanchal

Comment: I will post the solution please mark the post as an answer it will help other people who face a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this rule:

```
<rule name="app1 redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="app1.website.com" />
    </conditions> 
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://website.com/react1/app1/" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
 </rule>
```

[image]

[image]